# T-SQL function 'json_object' not supported in Visual Studio / SSDT?

Tags: json, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

Visual Studio will no longer build a project since I started using the `json_object` function.

Code sample:

```
declare @j varchar(max) = json_object(
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
)
```

This works fine in Azure SQL DB.

When I update the database to my SSDT project, the project will not build, throwing a bunch of errors.

```
SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near 'key1'.`, `SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ':'.
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ','.
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ','.
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ')'.  Expecting '(', or SELECT.
```

I updated Visual Studio and SSDT to the latest versions. SSDT is version 1.4.

Is there any way I can update or configure Visual Studio to the latest SQL version? If not, can I get Visual Studio to suppress the errors linked to json_object so building and publishing will succeed?

Comment: What is "Target platform" set to in your project settings?

Comment: 'Microsoft Azure SQL Database', which was also the platform where the code came from.

Comment: Where are you seeing the version of SSDT? My copy, in VS 2019 (which supports up to SQL Server 2019) is version 16.0.62205.05200 (and that's probably not up to date).

Comment: I gave you the version of the SSDT extension instead.
SQL Server Data Tools   17.2.31026.0
VisualStudio.17.Preview/17.5.0-pre.1.0+33103.201 (I just installed VS preview, but the issue remains.)

Comment: Why are using using the preview version? VS 2022 was released *ages* ago. `JSON_OBJECT` wasn't available when the preview release came out, and it won't have go updates for obvious reasons.

Comment: JSON_OBJECT is around since May 2022 and the latest VS preview version is from last November so I gave it a shot.  
I noticed that Azure Studio doesn't seem to have a problem with JSON_OBJECT, but I want to stick with Visual Studio for now.

Comment: I started replacing JSON_OBJECT with nested JSON_MODIFY functions, which have been around for a bit longer and do not upset Visual Studio. Not pretty, and JSON_MODIFY requires me to explicitly convert datetime and datetime2 date types, but it works fine.

Comment: Why is updating Visual Studio not an option..?

Comment: @Larnu, not sure if I understand your question. It is on the latest versions of Visual Studio and SSDT that I encountered the issue as stated in the question.
Until somebody got JSON_OBJECT actually working in the Visual Studio build feature, my best guess is that VS has not followed the latest T-SQL developments with regard to JSON (yet).